# Can I disable video auto-play on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, video

So Facebook has started to roll out auto-playing of videos in adverts and in news feeds. While it mutes them it still plays the video.

Is there a way I can disable this and return to the old behaviour of "click to play?"

(sub>I'm on Windows 7, running Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to go to [the video settings page](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=videos).

- From the settings tab, click the *Video Settings* link in the bottom left.
- Change *Auto-Play Videos* to "Off"

[image: video setttings tab]