# Disable Facebook video autoplay

Tags: facebook, facebook-videos, autoplay

I want desktop Facebook to stop autoplaying video, as it is annoying and tethering-unfriendly.

Disabling video autoplay [used to be possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/can-i-disable-video-auto-play-on-facebook), but as of August 2017 there is no "Auto-Play Videos" section in Settings>Videos.

Has the option been moved somewhere else?

Or has it become impossible to disable video autoplay?

*I tried with two different accounts on latest Firefox and Chromium.*

[image: Facebook: No setting to disable video autoplay]

Comment: @pnuts: For me videos started autoplaying just today.

Comment: @pnuts: Do you have the exact same as seen in the question I linked to? Plus quality/captions settings maybe?

Comment: It's still missing?

Comment: @arieljannai: Yes I just updated the screenshot.

Comment: Weird! [This is how mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49iNE.png). Maybe it's affected by different regions?